# AWS KMS client not returning an alias name

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kms

I've been using the `list_aliases()` method of KMS client since a while now without any issues. But recently it has stopped listing one of the alias names I want to use.

```
import boto3

kms_client = boto3.client('kms')

# Getting all the aliases from my KMS
key_aliases = kms_client.list_aliases()

key_aliases = key_aliases['Aliases']

# DO SOMETHING...
```

The `key_aliases` list above contains all the keys except the one I want to use. However, I can see from the AWS KMS UI that the key is enabled. Not sure why the `list_aliases()` method is not returning it.

Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Check the key has an alias and if not, it will not be listed.

Comment: The response might have been truncated. Have you checked whether the value of key_aliases['Truncated'] is true?

Comment: @Lamanus the key does have an alias, and has been working until now

Comment: @Vikyol you're right, `key_aliases['Truncated']=True`. I'll post an answer once I test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the response is truncated. The default number of aliases fetched by this API call is 50. You can increase the limit up to 100, which should solve your problem.

```
key_aliases = kms_client.list_aliases(Limit=100)
```

You should also check if the truncated field in the response is set to True. In that case, you can just make another API call to fetch the remaining results:

```
if key_aliases['Truncated'] is True:
   key_aliases = kms_client.list_aliases(Marker=key_aliases['NextMarker'])
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

def get_keys_arn(kmsclient,key_name):
#Marker = 'string'

```
alias_list = kmsclient.list_aliases(Limit=999)
if alias_list['Truncated'] is True:
    alias_list_trun = alias_list['Aliases']
    for alias in alias_list_trun:
        if alias["AliasName"] == "alias/" + key_name:
            return alias["TargetKeyId"]
    while alias_list['Truncated'] :
        alias_list = kmsclient.list_aliases(Limit=999,Marker=alias_list['NextMarker'])
        alias_list_trun = alias_list['Aliases']
        for alias in alias_list_trun:
            if alias["AliasName"] == "alias/" + key_name:
                return alias["TargetKeyId"]
else:
    alias_list= alias_list['Aliases']
    for alias in alias_list:
        if alias["AliasName"] == "alias/" + key_name:
            return alias["TargetKeyId"]
```